# Ubuntu black screen problem

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 18.10, visual-artifacts

I tried installing NVidia drivers, which went well, but after that, it started to have some horizontal rendering problems. Then, I decided to search the web. I thought I found a fix, but it broke my laptop.

[Here is a (PasteBin)](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gM2q7Dtbd9/) history of my commands (or see below):

```
ls
./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.73.run
sudo reboot
glxinfo | grep vendor
cd Downloads/Just.Sha...
everything normal now
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt install nvidia-current
sudo nvidia-xconfig
sudo reboot
here it broke, but, the login screen worked but then logged in, black screen and just the cursot not moving.
sudo apt update
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt clean
sudo apt install debsums
sudo apt clean
sudo debsums_init
sudo debsums -cs
sudo apt install --reinstall $(sudo dpkg -S $(sudo debsums -c) | cut -d : -f 1 | sort -u)
here, stuff really broke
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt install unity
sudo apt purge nvidia* bumblebee*
sudo shutdown -r now
sudo apt purge nvidia-*
sudo reboot
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
export DISPLAY=:0
ccsm <= error that i ignored like a fool
unity --replace
dconf reset -f /org/compiz
unity --reset-icons &disown
unity --reset-icons
sudo apt install gnome-panel
sudo reboot
sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
setsid unity
journalctl --user -xe
sudo apt install mate - attempt tobinstall mate
setsid mate
setsid MATE
setsid ubuntu-mate
mate
ubuntu-mate
sudo apt install -y expect
cat <<EOF | expect
set timeout -1
spaen sudo apt install -y ubuntu-mate-desktop
expect "Default display manager: "
send "lightdm\n"
expect eof
EOF

lightdm-gtk-greeter
sudo apt install lightdm-gtk-greeter
lightdm-gtk-greeter
set DISPLAY=:0
sudo lightdm-gtk-greeter
sudo reboot
```

Yes, I did write all of that all by hand.
Any ideas what to do?
Also, I use Ubuntu Cosmic Cuttlefish!
Here is an image of the situation:

[image: Here is an image of the situation]

Comment: Try switching to noveua driver which is open source

Comment: @Arpit Agarwal didnt work